# How do you filter results by site using Bing?

Tags: seo, search, bing

Using the following on Google and Yahoo filters results by site, but not in Bing:

```
site:example.com keyword
```

Is there a Bing equivalent?

Comment: Yea. Same thing!

Comment: @closetnoc That's funny, the word keyword in my example wasn't meant to be a search filter but that is what Bing seems to require. So, while Google/Yahoo seem to filter using site:example.com widgets, Bing requires site:example.com keyword widgets.

Comment: Well, I'll be ding danged!! That is why Bing still sucks I suppose. Which is a shame. I want someone to take it to Google a bit. Competition would keep G in check. Otherwise, G will continue to run a muck like it has from time to time.

Comment: @closetnoc That's only reason #376 why Bing sucks, not the only reason.

Comment: @Rob It blows my mind that after so many years and so much money spent that MSN/Bing cannot do a better job. But then again, it is Microsoft! Quite indicative.

Answer (score 1):

Bing supports the use of the site: filter in the search bar. I just performed a test using Bing and doing a search for a government department in Australia to filter just on departments website for the keyword earthquake.

The search string used was `site:ses.vic.gov.au earthquake` and the results returned was as expected only pages from that domain with the keyword of earthquake as can be seen from this link http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Ases.vic.gov.au+earthquake&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=site%3Ases.vic.gov.au+earthquake&sc=8-28&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=F9AC5EDF8C494F6FA247CF33415DC2CF.

Comment: It seems to mostly work for me for that site but still returns two results from other sites on the first results page: earthquaketrack.com/r/british-columbia-canada and www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/b-c-earthquake-6-6... If I search `site:ses.vic.gov.au keyword earthquake`, it comes up with only one result.

Comment: What happens for you if you search: `site:cbc.ca sports`?

Comment: The exact way that the search engines decide results to show is proprietary and while using the site filter should restrict it to a single domain it is possible that either the page has been mis-indexed or Bing has decided that the page should be included for some reason.

Comment: I don't think without the `keyword` present you can EXPECT (for whatever their proprietary reasons) only results for the site named in a query, with Bing, it would appear.